# Android SurfaceView filling background with a picture

Tags: android, background, surfaceview, image, fill

I'm a beginner/intermediate java-student and I just started working with android 2D programming. I'm working in surfaceView and want to set a backgroud, but the problem is I dont know how to make the background fill 100% of the screen, this is how I draw my background:

```
public GFXSurface(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.roadtest);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mThread = new ViewThread(this);
}
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick, place it after obtaining your bitmap

```
float scale = (float)mBitmap.getHeight()/(float)getHeight();
int newWidth = Math.round(mBitmap.getWidth()/scale);
int newHeight = Math.round(mBitmap.getHeight()/scale);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

then draw it like you already do :)

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunatly I have a stupid question. You told me to add this code "after obtaining my bitmap". Im not english so I dont really understand where you mean by this.

PS: Why the hell is it this hard to add a background? Java is usually smart.

Comment: Add the code just after :  mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.roadtest); Enjoy!

Comment: thank you :) Its weird cus Ive been looking over the lunarLander example so many times and from what I can see they never do anything to make the background full-screen, yet it is. If I try to use that same background it only fill like 1/5 of the screen... weird weird weird.

Comment: btw, found that if you put this in the constructor it sets the background for you:
    mDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);